# Get values from select box when select and unselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

How to get values from the `select box` when you use the select option and also how to get values you deselect the selected option

*I am using this code*

```
$('.select2-multiple').select2MultiCheckboxes({
    placeholder: "Choose multiple elements",
})
```

I have tried with below code for the `change event`

```
    $("#sel-01").change(function()  
    {    
         var  value =  this.value;
         if (value != "") 
         {
            alert("Selected")
         }
         else
         {
            alert("Not selected")
         }
    });
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mn123/z7aL1gf6/4/)**

```js
/**
 * jQuery Select2 Multi checkboxes
 * - allow to select multi values via normal dropdown control
 * 
 * author      : wasikuss
 * repo        : https://github.com/wasikuss/select2-multi-checkboxes/tree/select2-3.5.x
 * inspired by : https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/411
 * License     : MIT
 */

jQuery(function($) {
  $('.select2-multiple').select2MultiCheckboxes({
    placeholder: "Choose multiple elements",
  })

  $("#sel-01").change(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    if (value != "") {
      alert("Selected")
    } else {
      alert("Not selected")
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.select2-result-label .wrap:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  color: #999;
  content: "\f096";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.select2-result-label .wrap.checked:before {
  content: "\f14a";
}

.select2-result-label .wrap {
  margin-left: 15px;
}


/* not required css */

.row {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/wasikuss/select2-multi-checkboxes/select2-3.5.x/select2.multi-checkboxes.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <select name="sel-01" id="sel-01" class="select2-multiple">
    <option></option>
    <option value="100">india</option>
    <option value="200">California</option>
    <option value="300">New York</option>
    <option value="400">Texas</option>
    <option value="500">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: well does it have a change event? No clue what the library is so can't help and not going to google the documentation which probably has it listed.

Comment: @epascarello Yes , I have updated the question

Comment: RTM: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a selector to get all the options inside the select element here: http://jsfiddle.net/z7aL1gf6/78/

```
var options = Array.from($('#sel-01 option'));
     var checked = [];
     var unchecked = [];
     options.forEach(opt => {
       if (opt.className === 'checked') {
        checked.push(opt.value)
      } else {
        unchecked.push(opt.value)
      }
     });
     // check console: View -> Developer Tools
     console.log('CHECKED:',checked);
     console.log('UNCHECKED',unchecked);
```

Please let me know if that gets you closer to your solution.

Comment: hello dave, why it shows  event.added is null error when select and deselect option,

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the onchange event, and add one function in your select2MultiCheckboxes,

```
jQuery(function($) {
      $('.select2-multiple').select2MultiCheckboxes({
        placeholder: "Choose multiple elements",
        formatSelection: function(selected) { 
            console.log(selected); // you will get the dropdown selected values in array format.
            return selected;
          }
      });
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine for you:

I have used `selected.added` to get your *selected value*.

and by combining an `each` function with added class `.checked` I have get the *unselected value*

For getting the total value of the *selected value* I have combined the array with a `for` loup.

```js
/**
 * jQuery Select2 Multi checkboxes
 * - allow to select multi values via normal dropdown control
 * 
 * author      : wasikuss
 * repo        : https://github.com/wasikuss/select2-multi-checkboxes/tree/select2-3.5.x
 * inspired by : https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/411
 * License     : MIT
 */

jQuery(function($) {
  $('.select2-multiple').select2MultiCheckboxes({
    placeholder: "Choose multiple elements"
  });

  $('.select2-multiple').on('change', function(selected) {
    var selected = selected.added,
      UnSelect = [],
      total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
      total += selected[i] << 0;
    }
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {


      if (!$(this).hasClass('checked')) {
        var UnS = $(this).attr('value');
        UnSelect.push(UnS);
      }
    });
    console.log('Unselected = ' + UnSelect, 'Selected = ' + selected);
    console.log(total);
  });

});
```

```css
.select2-result-label .wrap:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 4px;
  font-family: fontAwesome;
  color: #999;
  content: "\f096";
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}

.select2-result-label .wrap.checked:before {
  content: "\f14a";
}

.select2-result-label .wrap {
  margin-left: 15px;
}


/* not required css */

.row {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wasikuss/select2-multi-checkboxes/select2-3.5.x/select2.multi-checkboxes.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.4/select2.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <select name="sel-01" id="sel-01" class="select2-multiple">
    <option value="100">india</option>
    <option value="200">California</option>
    <option value="300">New York</option>
    <option value="400">Texas</option>
    <option value="500">Wyoming</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/90hgtcx8/) for you if you want.

Hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: hello, Webber thanks for the answer Its working fine. Now how can I add the values?

Comment: @ManjunathCa add value to where.?

Comment: I have updated the question, Changed option values string to integer , I need the addition of selected values,

Comment: I have changed the values as well, but what you want exactly, you want to add the selected values to one value.?? or just combine them.? I don't get it.

Comment: I want to add the selected values to one value,

Comment: @ManjunathCa I have Updated my code please do check it.

Comment: hello, Webber it says TypeError: event.added is null when I select and unselect single checkbox.

Comment: @ManjunathCa Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168718/discussion-between-webber-and-manjunath-ca).